# ruby remove variable length string from regular expression leaving hyphen

Tags: ruby

I have a string such as this: "im@ -33.870816,151.203654"
I want to extract the two numbers including the hyphen.
I tried this:

```
mystring = "im@ -33.870816,151.203654"
/\D*(\-*\d+\.\d+),(\-*\d+\.\d+)/.match(mystring)
```

This gives me:

```
33.870816,151.203654
```

How do I get the hyphen?

I need to do this in ruby

Edit: I should clarify, the "im@ " was just an example, there can be any set of characters before the numbers.  the numbers are mostly well formed with the comma.  I was having trouble with the hyphen (-)

Edit2: Note that the two nos are lattidue, longitude.  That pattern is mostly fixed.  However, in theory, the preceding string can be arbitrary.  I don't expect it to have nos. or hyphen, but you never know.

Comment: gives what match? 1-st? by default regexp is greedy so `\D*` matches hyphen but not \-*. Try append `?` to `\D*` = `\D*?`, this will make that expression non-greedy

Comment: The non-greedy option is also good :). A bit slower though.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
arr = "im@ -33.2222,151.200".split(/[, ]/)[1..-1]
```

and arr is `["-33.2222", "151.200"]`, (using the [split method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split)).

now

`arr[0].to_f` is `-33.2222` and `arr[1].to_f` is `151.2`

EDIT: stripped "im@" part with [1..-1] as suggested in comments.

EDIT2: also, this work regardless of what the first characters are.

Comment: Again, +1 for most of the work, but why not shift the `"@im"` off with something like `[1..-1]`? Leaving extra results in the array isn't that disimilar from the original string.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to capture the two numbers with the hyphen you can use this regex:

```
> str = "im@ -33.870816,151.203654"
> str.match(/([\d.,-]+)/).captures
=> ["33.870816,151.203654"]
```

**Edit:** now it captures hyphen.
This one captures each number separetely: http://rubular.com/r/NNP2OTEdiL

**Note:** Using `String#scan` will match *all* ocurrences of given pattern, in this case

```
> str.scan /\b\s?([-\d.]+)/
=> [["-33.870816"], ["151.203654"]] # Good, but flattened version is better
> str.scan(/\b\s?([-\d.]+)/).flatten
=> ["-33.870816", "151.203654"]
```

I recommend you playing around a little with [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/NNP2OTEdiL). There's also some docs about regegular expressions with Ruby:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UJ
http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html

Comment: +1, but `str.match(/-([\d.,-]+)/)[0].split ","` seems a little bit better to me.

Comment: How can this be correct? It gives ["33.870816,151.203654"]. I don't see any hypen..

Comment: Oops, misunderstood comma for hyphen.

Comment: I edited the question.  The initial string can be arbitrary.  I don't expect it to have numbers or -.  Suppose it does will it break your solution?  Note that the pattern of the 2 nos. (it's lattitude,longitude) is fixed.  It may be preceded by arbitrary string.  You can ignore this if you want.  I am all set for now.  Suppose i have str = "adfdf76sdf 33.870816,151.203654", will your solution work.  Actually, I just tried, and it doesn't.  I'll try to figure out later.  Thanks for your help

Comment: You are right, it will capture any sequence of digits including hyphens and/or periods, thus capturing the '76' in you example. Updated to solve that.

Comment: Sorry to bother.  I think there's still a problem.  I think the key is the space before the hyphen.  Suppose I have: "adfdf -33.870816,-151.203654" then the match works.  however, if I have "adfdf-33.870816,-151.203654" (no space before the hyphen), then it doesn't pick up the hyphen.  Is there some way to pick up the 2 nos., regardless of what comes before? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Edited to cover that hole.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex doesn't work because the hyphen is caught by `\D`, so you have to modify it to catch only the right set of characters.

`[^0-9-]*` would be a good option.